# Return array element NOT present in the second array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to return the element of first array NOT present in the second, return empty array if both are present in second array

`arr1 = [' name', 'email']`

`arr2 = [ 'name', 'card_number', 'role', 'age' ]`

expect to return ['email'] in this example

tried to use filter but didn't succeed.

anyone can help, please?

Comment: Can you please post your attempt with `.filter()`?

Comment: is space here `' name'` a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look if the other array does not includ the value for filtering.

```js
const
    arr1 = ['name', 'email'],
    arr2 = ['name', 'card_number', 'role', 'age'],
    result = arr1.filter(v => !arr2.includes(v));

console.log(result);
```